# Approximation of $\sin \pi x$ on $-1 \leq x \leq 1$

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

I am stuck in the following problem:
I wish to give an approximation of $\sin(\pi x)$ on $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, when using the polynomial $$F_N(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_kx^{2k+1}$$
with the coefficients $a_k$ chosen to minimize the integral:
$$F(a_0, a_1, \cdots a_N)=\int_{-1}^{1}(F_N(x)   - \sin \pi x)^2dx$$
Is it possible to show that: 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{a_k}{2(k+j)+3}= I_j = \int_{0}^{1}x^{2j+1} \sin \pi x dx$$ for $j=0,1, \cdots N$.

I started by $$F(a_0, a_1, \cdots a_N)=\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_kx^{2k+1}- \sin \pi x\right)^2dx$$

But to be honest, I haven't got a clue where to begin and where to continue. I hope somebody can help me

Comment: Hint: your $I_j$ are just constants. E.g. $I_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}$ and $I_1 = \frac{\pi^2 - 6}{\pi^3}$.

Comment: Oh is your question on showing the given equation, and not actually computing $a_k$?

Comment: Correct, not actually computing $a_k$, but showing, the relationship between the sum and the integral. Today, tried it for 4 hours but didn't come any further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your start is correct. Consider
$$
F(a_0, \dots, a_N) = \int \limits_{-1}^1 \left( \sum \limits_{k=0}^N a_k x^{2k+1} - \sin(\pi x) \right)^2 dx
$$
Using the $L^2$ dot product
$$
\langle f, g \rangle := \int \limits_{-1}^1 f(x) g(x) dx
$$
and the corresponding $L^2$-norm $\| f \|_2 := \sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle}$, you can rewrite your starting expression as (using the abbreviation $\sum \dots$ for the sum and assuming that all coefficients are real, i.e. $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $j$)
$$
F(a_0, \dots, a_N) = \int \limits_{-1}^1 \left( \sum \limits_{k=0}^N a_k x^{2k+1} - \sin(\pi x) \right)^2 dx = \left\| \sum \dots - \sin(\pi x) \right\|_2^2 = \\ 
= \langle \sum \dots, \sum \dots \rangle - 2 \langle \sum \dots, \sin(\pi x) \rangle + \langle \sin(\pi x), \sin(\pi x) \rangle
$$
Due to the linearity of the dot product, you can write this as
$$
\sum \limits_{k,j=0}^N a_k a_j \int \limits_{-1}^1 x^{2(k+j)+2} dx - 2 \sum \limits_{j=0}^N a_j \int \limits_{-1}^1 \sin(\pi x) x^{2j+1} dx + \int \limits_{-1}^1 \sin^2(\pi x) dx
$$
which evaluates to
$$
\sum \limits_{k,j=0}^N a_k a_j \int \limits_{-1}^1 x^{2(k+j)+2} dx - 2 \sum \limits_{j=0}^N a_j \int \limits_{-1}^1 \sin(\pi x) x^{2j+1} dx + 1
$$
The first integral simply has the value $\frac{2}{2(k+j)+3}$ by elementary integration. Now factoring out the sum with index $j$ finally yields:
$$
2 \sum \limits_{j = 0}^N a_j \left( \sum \limits_{k=0}^N \frac{a_k}{2(k+j)+3} - \int \limits_{-1}^1 \sin(\pi x) x^{2j+1} dx \right) + 1
$$
The expression in brackets yields exactly the term $I_j$ you're looking for.

Comment: And can we say by minimizing the value between  brackets is equal to 'zero'. So $I_j$ yields exactly the required equation?

Comment: The term in brackets is basically a system of linear equations of size $N+1$ for the coefficients $a_k$ $(k=0, \dots, N)$. It seems that this system is solvable for the corresponding right-hand side determined by the $N+1$ integrals (I tried it for $N=2$, but I didn't check the general situation).

Comment: Can you clarify, the proof needed is for the integral of the sin term (the $I_j$ part to be from 1 to 0, but the integral in brackets goes from 1 to -1 in your solution, so is not of the form required.

Comment: OK, you can rescue it, the $sin(\pi x)$ is odd and $x^{2j+1}$ is odd, hence the integrand is a product of two odd functions ie. an even function.  As you are integrating over a symmetric interval you can take the limits from 1 to 0 and pick up a factor of 2 outside the integral, but can we clarify where that 2 goes, as we now have a factor of 4 multiplying the integral.

Comment: Hey Tom, yes you're absolutely right, I also noticed the difference in the lower integral bound (being 0 in the original question and -1 in my answer). To be honest, I assumed that this is a typo in @mathpieuler's question...However, if this is *not* the case (i.e. the lower integral bound is actually 0), then of course, one may apply the "trick" you mentioned and arrive at the integral from 0 to 1, but then the coefficients aren't correct anymore...maybe mathpieuler may help us out with this question and tell us what the correct lower integral bound is?

Comment: I know where the problem comes from and have contacted the author, but I got 'it's OK, check your arithmetic'.  I've checked though and it's definitely wrong, can you double-check as well?  The limits are apparently -1 and 1 but that doesn't make sense.  I'll see if the author double-checks again, but could you also go back through it as I feel there has to be a mistake.

Comment: Is there some reason why there would be a 4 in front of the summation of $a_k$?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no mistake in my answer, or I'm just too blind to see it ;-) Of course, there *might* me a mistake somewhere, I'm not claiming that I've done everything correct...As for your question: I don't see where a factor 4 should come from; Basically, the whole derivation of my answer is nothing but simple usage of elementary Hilbert space theory in $L^2([-1,1])$ and properties of the $L^2$ dot product. The question of @mathpieuler actually refers to finding a best approximation of $\sin(\pi x)$ with polynomials of odd degree $x^{2j+1}$ in the $L^2$ sense.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  It seems especially strange that you would have to change the limits from the original ones, it doesn't quite add up.  I will see if I can get confirmation from the authors that it is a typo.

Comment: I just can agree that the question is correct. I double checked it. :-)

Comment: I've had confirmation as well that the limits are correct.  Can you we find the mistake and fix this, as the answer is not correct as it stands?

Comment: Or can we find an alternative way of solving the problem?

Comment: Is it that there is a factor of two in front of the double summation to account for cross-terms over the double sum, if so that rescues everything, as you would then have a total factor of 4 for both parts.

Comment: @mathpieuler: Can you un-tick Complexflo's answer to this question as the problem has not been solved satisfactorily imo.

Comment: In the meantime, I double-checked my answer once again - couldn't find any error in it under the assumption $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $j$ (as already mentioned, I don't claim that there *might* not be an error, though!). Hence, assuming that I've done everything correct, two possibilities remain: Either, the exercise of @mathpieuler is incorrect (i.e. the lower integral bound actually *is* $-1$ and the question's author has a typo in the original question) or mathpieuler's question contains a typo somewhere...However, sorry for this rather unsatisfying answer :/

Comment: @ComplexFlo: I cannot see any mistake either, but I have had adamant confirmation from the author that the question is correct as it stands, so not much more we can do unfortunately.

Comment: Incidentally, although our resolution of this one was maybe incomplete, I think there is a second part of the question: this is to determine a recurrence relation for the integrals we defined as $I_j$ and show in particular that it takes the form  $I_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{2n(2n+1)}{{\pi}^2}I_{n-1}$ where $n=1,2,...$ and $I_{0}=\frac{1}{\pi}$ and so deduce that $I_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{{\pi}^{2k+1}}\frac{(2n+1)!}{(2n-2k+1)!}$ where $n$ is greater than or equal to 0,  do you have any ideas how this would be done?

Comment: Yes, your mentioned recurrence relation $$I_n = \frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{2n(2n+1)}{\pi^2} I_{n-1}$$ is correct, as can easily be shown using integration by parts twice. The representation of $I_n$ as the (finite) sum then follows by induction, I guess. Nice!